# .NET 6 - Google Firestore - Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Error loading native library libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.dylib on Apple M1

Tags: c#, google-cloud-firestore, apple-m1, .net-6.0

I have a .NET 6 project that is using Google.Cloud.Firestore 2.4.0, and I'm trying to configure the Firestore. However, every time I try to build a **FirestoreDb** instance, I get the following error.

```cs
Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: Error loading native library "/Users/[user]/Code/[project]/platform/WebApi/bin/Release/net6.0/runtimes/osx-x64/native/libgrpc_csharp_ext.x64.dylib". 
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.UnmanagedLibrary..ctor(String[] libraryPathAlternatives)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethodsUsingExplicitLoad()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.LoadNativeMethods()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension..ctor()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeExtension.Get()
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.NativeMethods.Get()
   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.GrpcNativeInit()
   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment..ctor()
   at Grpc.Core.GrpcEnvironment.AddRef()
   at Grpc.Core.Channel..ctor(String target, ChannelCredentials credentials, IEnumerable`1 options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.GrpcCore.GrpcCoreAdapter.CreateChannelImpl(String endpoint, ChannelCredentials credentials, GrpcChannelOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.GrpcAdapter.CreateChannel(String endpoint, ChannelCredentials credentials, GrpcChannelOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase`1.CreateChannel(String endpoint, ChannelCredentials credentials)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase`1.CreateCallInvoker()
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClientBuilder.BuildImpl()
   at Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClientBuilder.Build()
```

This is my **Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var builder = WebHost
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configurationBuilder) =>
    {

        if (context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            ConfigureFirestoreEmulator(configurationBuilder);
        }
    });

static void ConfigureFirestoreEmulator(IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST", "localhost:8080");

    var db = new FirestoreDbBuilder
    {
        ProjectId = "dev",
        EmulatorDetection = Google.Api.Gax.EmulatorDetection.EmulatorOnly
    }.Build();
    
}

var app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

This is my **firebase.json**

```json
{
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

I'm running on **macOS Big Sur Version 11.6 (20G165)** using **.NET 6.0.100-rc.2.21505.57**

How would you approach this issue so I can use Firestore from my current computer?

Comment: This seems like a compatibility issue with the CPU. Found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65963076/16531441) with similar error with a workaround.

Comment: I have looked at workarounds similar to that one, however, the issue is that dependency is coming from a library so any time I'd like to update it I would have to apply the workaround. Thank you for the link this has been my best option so far.